# Python3: how can I set python 3.6 as default?

Tags: python

I have installed python 3.6 in an Ubuntu 16.04 platform that had previously python 3.5

now if I check the installed version I have:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3492656 Nov 12 19:46 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Nov 12 19:46 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464368 Nov 12 16:27 /usr/bin/python3.5
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4464368 Nov 12 16:27 /usr/bin/python3.5m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4719712 Dec 25 04:54 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4719712 Dec 25 04:54 /usr/bin/python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 Mar 23  2016 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.5m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 24  2017 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

However if I check the version that is running is:

```
python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
```

The same in the jupyter notebook

[image]

How can I set `Python 3.6.7` as default instead of `Python 3.5.2`?

Comment: Try `sudo update-alternatives --config python3`.

Comment: @Jos I would oppose updating alternatives because some packages strictly depends on Python 3.5 and updating alternatives can break things up. Need to look at some other workaround

Comment: You are right, but then it would have been slightly risky to install Python 3.6 in the first place. In this case, I suppose OP needs to use a full path to the 3.6.7 executable?

Comment: I agree with Kulfy, you should under no circumstances change what the system's `python3` executable points to, that would break many applications. You can still manually run Python 3.6 with the command `python3.6` instead of `python3`, or you can make a Bash alias like `alias py='python3.6'` if you want to save you some typing.

Comment: @ByteCommander ... or use shebang?

Comment: @Jos Downloading and changing symlinks are two independent things. Downloading might not break things but symlinks can. Python3 is symlink to Python3.5

Comment: @Kulfy the previous one was related to the installation that I did. But I will remove it.

Comment: @ByteCommander I did not understand how to make it. Sorry I am not really familiar with it.

Comment: @emax The post I linked above describes how to make an alias, among other things. Whether you want to make something for Python 3 instead of 2 or 3.6 instead of 3.5 is not much of a difference. Just remember not to touch the system's internal symlinks, only configure stuff for your user, like aliases (or just type out `python3.6` if needed)

Comment: @ByteCommander Hi, I saw it. Should I do alias `python='/usr/bin/python3.6?'`

Comment: Whatever you want to type in your shell to open the 3.6 interpreter. Personally I'd use something completely different that doesn't shadow any existing names, like e.g. `py36` instead. But that is your choice, as it is only an alias, it will not effect anything but your interactive shells.

Comment: @ByteCommander the problem is how can it work on jupyter notebook?

Comment: @emax see https://stackoverflow.com/q/28831854/4518341